# Getting the number that is not multiplied by 200

Tags: vb.net

I want to get the number that is not multiplied by 200. Per example

```
X=900
Y=200
Q=X/Y = 4.50 // I want to get 100 from results
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the Modulus operator.

In VB you can do this as follows:

```
X=900
Y=200
Q=X Mod Y
```

Q will be equal to 100.